# how do i set input type=button and input type=submit at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a html form which which sends when I press the submit button-(input type=submit)..
Also on the same button, I have a onclick event which fires on pressing the button, but as the type of the button=submit, the window.location in my fired script does not work, it works fine when I change button input type to button, but the html form submit does not work..
Is there any way both that work simultaneously.. and please don't tell posting form by ajax post..

here is my html button

```
<input type="submit" class="submit-login" name="forgotpass" id="" onclick="forgotfunction()"/>
```

here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function forgotfunction(){
    var len = $('#forgetpass').val();
    if (len.length == 10){
        var num = "<?php echo $_SESSION['msg'];unset($_SESSION['msg']);?>"; //getting error from parameter.
        alert(num);
        if(num=="success")
            $('#modalLink').trigger("click");
        if(num=="cannotsend")
            alert("Error! Cannot send mail.,Please try Again!");
        if(num=="invalid")
            alert("Mobile number is  not Registered");
        alert(num);
        alert(window.location.href.split("?")[0]);
        window.location = window.location.href.split("?")[0];//reloading page
        //$('#aforgot').trigger('click');

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code refreshes the page, you cannot both refresh the page and submit the form at the same time, even using a button input, and submitting the form manually.

Comment: the refresh comes after submitting the form..Why is the error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an input which is more than 1 type, ie. a `submit` and a `button`. To do what you want, set the type to `button`, then in your processing logic, submit the form manually. Try this:

```
<input type="button" class="submit-login" name="forgotpass" id="" />
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.submit-login').click(forgotfunction);
});

function forgotfunction() {
    var len = $('#forgetpass').val();
    if (len.length == 10) {
        var num = "<?php echo $_SESSION['msg']; unset($_SESSION['msg']);?>"; //getting error from parameter.

        if (num == "success")
            $('#modalLink').trigger("click");

        if (num == "cannotsend")
            alert("Error! Cannot send mail.,Please try Again!");

        if (num == "invalid")
            alert("Mobile number is  not Registered");

        window.location = window.location.href.split("?")[0]; //reloading page
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set button `type="button"`.

and submit the form on the button click event by:
 `$("#formId").submit()`

Answer (score 0):

I would definitly go for a button tag..

As stated [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON), it's default behaviour is "submit" if it does belong to a form element. (it also has a value attribute)

```
<button>Submit</button>
```